# max value in a column and its corresponding row without repeated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataset like this

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':["a","b","c","a","a","a"],
            'score':[100, 98, 99,100,100,100],
            'job':["m","n","o","m","m","m"]})
```

I wanna find the name with the highest score(which is " a " with the score "100")

I tried this code

```
df[['name','score']][df.score == df.score.max()]
```

the output is like this

```
     name    score
0      a       100
3      a       100
4      a       100
5      a       100
```

How can I get rid of repeated rows and have one row displayed?

Comment: `df.loc[df['score'].idxmax(), 'name']`?

Comment: I know I can slice the table with [0:1] but I need a more expert way

Comment: What if you have several names with the highest score?

Comment: `I wanna find the name with the highest score` you mentioned you only wanted to find name, didnot mention about score. In that case use `df.loc[df['score'].idxmax()]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates`:

```
df[['name','score']][df.score == df.score.max()].drop_duplicates()
  name  score
0    a    100
```

Comment: Consider `df.loc[df.score == df.score.max(), ['name','score']].drop_duplicates()`